# Expectation of the product of a sequence in a simple Markov chain

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes

This is probably simple to those who know stochastic processes, but I am finding it difficult to understand how to solve expectations of a sequence.
 If $y(t)$ is a simple Markov chain where $y(t) = r\cdot y(t-1)$ and $r$ is a constant, what is the unconditional expectation of the product of the last $k$ observations $y(t-k)\cdot y(t-k+1)\dots y(t-1)\cdot y(t)$? I know how to solve it up to $t-1$ : $E[y(t-1)\cdot y(t)] = r$, but I need help in how to solve $E[y(t-2)\cdot y(t-1)\cdot y(t)]$, for example. Would be grateful for even a lead.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math,Stack exchange.  If you put maths between dollar signs it looks a bit better.  In your question, why do you describe this as a Markov chain? If $r$ is a constant where is the randomness coming from?